# how to add another html tag

Tags: php, html, dom, tags

```
$iframes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
foreach ($iframes as $iframeViejo) {
   $iframeMainn = $doc->createElement('iframe');
   $iframeNuevo->setAttribute('src', $iframeViejo->getAttribute('src'));
   $iframeNuevo->setAttribute('width','560');
   $iframeNuevo->setAttribute('height','615');
   $figureNuevo = $doc->createElement('figure');
   $figureNuevo->setAttribute('class','op-interactive');
   $figureNuevo->appendChild($iframeNuevo);
   $iframeViejo->parentNode->replaceChild($figureNuevo, $iframeViejo);
}
```

but i want to add another iframe tag, because i want this output:

```
<figure class="class"><iframe><iframe src="src" width="xxx" height="xxx"></iframe><iframe></figure>
```

could you please help me

Comment: add iframes via for loop and then individually? is that what you are asking for?

Comment: yes i need to add another iframe

Comment: what object is $iframeNuevo

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the JavaScript code, You can try**

```
function CreateTag(TAG){
    return document.createElement(TAG);
}

var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
var totalIframe = iframes.length;

for(var i=0; i<totalIframe; i++){
    figure = CreateTag('figure');  /*Create <figure> Tag*/
    iframe = CreateTag('iframe');  /*Create <iframe> Tag*/

    figure.setAttribute('class','ClassName');  /*Set class="ClassName"*/

    iframe.setAttribute('src',iframes[i].src); /*Set main iframe src to new <iframe> src*/
    iframe.setAttribute('width','200');  /*Set new <iframe> width*/
    iframe.setAttribute('height','100'); /*Set new <iframe> height*/

    figure.appendChild(iframe);     /*Append new <figure> to <figure> Tag*/
    iframes[i].replaceWith(figure); /*Replace main <iframe> with new <figure> Tag*/
}
```

> **Note:** Above code will output like as below

```
<figure class="ClassName"><iframe src="{main-iframe-src}" width="200" height="100"><iframe></figure>
```